# An interchangeable key/value HashMap Set structure

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

### Background

Create a series of SQL JOIN statements using two operands: primary and secondary. The generic form of the JOIN statement is:

```
JOIN primary primary ON (secondary.id == primary.id)
```

### Problem

The code currently iterates over a list of primary and secondary operands, as follows:

```
for( Bundle primaryOperand : bundleComparators ) {
  for( Bundle secondaryOperand : sortedBundles ) {
```

The problem is that the nested loop generates the following:

```
JOIN primary primary ON (secondary.id == primary.id)
JOIN secondary secondary ON (primary.id == secondary.id)
```

The second join is superfluous and, in this case, causes an error. The duplication can be eliminated with the following hypothetical data structure:

```
if( !interchangeableMap.contains( primaryOperand, secondaryOperand ) ) {
    interchangeableMap.put( primaryOperand, secondaryOperand );

    outputJoin( primaryOperand, secondaryOperand );
}
```

Where `interchangeableMap.contains(...)` will return **true** if `primaryOperand` is mapped to `secondaryOperand` *or* `secondaryOperand` is mapped to `primaryOperand`.

### Questions

1. Does such a data structure exist in the Java libraries?
2. If not, what data structures would you use for its implementation?

### Ideas

My first thought is to create a class that contains two `HashMap`s. Checking for containment queries the two `HashMap`s to see if one map contains the primary and secondary operands or the other map contains the secondary and primary operands. Insertions put the two operand combinations into their respective `HashMap`s.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution based on @**roland**'s suggestion:

```
public final class Pair {
  private final Object a;
  private final Object b;

  public Pair(Object a, Object b) {
    this.a = a; 
    this.b = b;
  }

  @Override public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(o == null || !(o instanceof Pair)) 
      return false;

    Pair that = (Pair) o;
    return this.a.equals(that.a) && this.b.equals(that.b) 
      || this.a.equals(that.b) && this.b.equals(that.a);
  }

  @Override public int hashCode() {
    return a.hashCode() ^ b.hashCode();
  }
}
```

Then:

```
Set<Pair> set = new HashSet<Pair>();
for(Bundle primaryOperand : bundleComparators) {
  for(Bundle secondaryOperand : sortedBundles) {
    Pair p = new Pair(primaryOperand.id, secondaryOperand.id);
    if(set.contains(p)) 
      continue;

    set.add(p);
    outputJoin(primaryOperand, secondaryOperand);
  }
}
```

A subtle point about the solution: you must also override the `hashCode()` method (hash value must reflect the equality relation), but you must do it in a symmetric way, that is: the hash value of `<a,b>` must be == to that of `<b,a>`

Comment: Thank you. Unless I am mistaken, the `Map` interface does not define a `contains( object, object )` method. There is `containsKey()` and `containsValue()`, but I cannot use them independently.

Comment: The `swap` method and conditional can be removed by checking the swapped values in `equals`? (Also, the `new Pair` can be removed, then.)

Answer (score 1):

Another idea would be to define a new Class `OperatorPair` that overrides `equals()` and use a `Set` of those, again to be checked with `contains()`. But your solution should work well, too.

(Also, if you do this, you should override `hashCode()` as well, for example you could calculate it based on the names of the operands... see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java) for details.)

Answer (score 1):

I hope I'm not completely wrong: 
You can use a `HashMap` and put each mapping twice: `(primary, secondary)` and `(secondary, primary)`. For a lookup you would not check for `contains` but `(get(primary) == seconday) or (get(secondary) == primary)`.

The apache commons library contains the [BidiMap](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/BidiMap.html) which allows a "bidirectional lookup between key and values". So you use this one too, to avoid the double insert