# is there a map that will supply me hashing in both direction?

Tags: java, hashmap

I hold the following map

```
      Map<Integer, List<String>>
```

when I add a new string to a certain int I just add it to the list of that int value in my map.
Now, I also need to remove it from the last list it was located in.
I will elaborate for a second :
It is not the same instance of the string. I get an int and a  String, I need to add it and remove it from the former List in the map that held the same string value.

This means that I need to hold another map of String to Integer ?
Do I need to maintain two collections?
thanks.

Comment: See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430170/how-to-create-a-2-way-map-in-java)

Comment: @User: Although the titles are similar, that link describes a 1:1 relationship between the `int` and the `String`. If I'm reading the above correctly, it's not 1:1, an `int` refers to a `List` of `String`.

Comment: @user: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828647/an-interchangeable-key-value-hashmap-set-structure/5828707#5828707

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's kind of like a BiMap, but since your relationship is assymetrical (one `int` refers to a `List` of `String`s whereas a `String` can only refer to one `int`), it's not going to be a perfect mtach.

It sounds to me as though you want two maps, the first being your `Map<Integer, List<String>>` and the second being a `Map<String, Integer>`. You'd want to encapsulate this in class, of course. Adding a new string is then:

1. If there's an entry for the `String` in `Map<String, Integer>`,

   - Get the `Integer` from that list.
   - Use it to look up the `List` from your `Map<Integer, List<String>>` and remove the `String` from it.
2. Add the `String` to the relevant `List` in your `Map<Integer, List<String>>`
3. Add an entry mapping the `String` to the `Integer` in the `Map<String, Integer>`.

Comment: Just a short question to the OP. Are you sure that all your strings are unique? Can two different ints map to the same string? This won't work in that case.

Comment: @Kaj: In the question he says *"when I add a new string to a certain int I just add it to the list of that int value in my map. Now, I also need to remove it from the last list it was located in."* which I think is pretty clear.

Comment: It's very clear for the direction of an int to a string, but that does not say anything about if the strings are unique over the whole map. I don't know anything about the data of the OP. But this will fail if 1 maps to "foo" and 42 also maps to "foo". It will work for int -> string, but not the other way around unless the strings are unique over the whole map.

Comment: @Kaj: He specifically says that when adding a string "to a certain int", he "...also need[s] to remove it from the last list it was located in." That tells us that a `String` can be related to at most one `int`. Well, that plus the fact he accepted the answer. ;-)

Comment: I know that he accepted the answer, and I know that it's most likely that your answer is 100% correct. Just wanted to make sure that he wouldn't get into trouble in the future because he hadn't thought about if all strings are unique or not. He says "add a new string to a certain int". That does to me only mean that the string is new for that int. It doesn't say that it hasn't been mapped to another int already.

Comment: @Kaj: (Don't worry, I understand you're just trying to help the guy out.) *"It doesn't say that it hasn't been mapped to another int already."* The key part is the second half of that sentence: "I also need to remove it from the last list it was located in". With that rule in place, we know for certain that a string *cannot* ever be in the lists of two ints at the same time.

Comment: I've seen that part, but I've seen lots and lots of posts (I'm not new to forums, I have about 30k posts on the javaforums) where people haven't been thinking it through. The part that I quoted indicates to me that he's thinking in the context of one int and a list, and not in the context of the whole map. I'm however guessing and agree that I'm most likely wrong :)

Comment: @Kaj: Yeah, people do sometimes make mistakes in their wording, no question. :-)

Comment: Hey guyz :-0) . My strings are unique (originally from toString() of a sequence). (And this debate reminded me again that this site is amazing ) 10x.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [Guava's BiMap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html).